# When to delete a temp file?

Tags: scripting, coding-style, standards, temporary-files

Is there a standard or a common way when to delete a temporary file?
I'm currently writing a script in which I'm using many of them, but when should I remove them?

1. Delete the file after you used it / won't need it afterwards
2. Delete all temp files at the end of the script

Comment: Logic will tell you that if you need it afterwards then *don't* delete it.

Comment: I know but in case I use a lot of temp files, It may slows down the process when after a loop I need to delete many files before the script can do further work. I'm not talking about just 1 file.

Comment: What you're asking then is really very case-specific.
Although, if you are creating many files - you *will* have to delete them at some point, and it *will* take more time the longer you wait to do it (more files will be created as more script runs will be called)

Answer (score 0):

I would give the temp files a specific directory or a specific file extension. And then delete it at the end of the script (all inside the temp-dir or all with the extension). I prefer doing it this way because:

1) If there are a lot of files you might forget one if you delete them by their names

2) If you still needs one of them later inside the code it's still there.